# How to change Camera Position in google map using android?

Tags: android, google-maps, position, google-maps-markers

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng)
            .zoom(20)
            .build();
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

When I animate the marker, by default the camera animates to the center of the `Map`. I want to animate camera position to center-top like(zomato map activity having, when I clicking the marker the bottom sheet has to overflow the map at the same time marker with map move to top.how can I do this?)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Change your start location in`onMapReady`

```
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lng), zoom));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
```

Comment: map.animate camera for animating marker location center.but I want to customize camera position center to some other places.